# save a plot in python

Tags: python, plot

I plotted something in python and I want to save the plot using `plt.savefig("g3.19e10.01024")`. But it doesn't let me, as the program sees the `.19e10` as an extension which is not recognized by the system. How can I solve this, keeping the same name for the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an appropriate filename extension to your current filename. You could use `jpg` or `png`:

```
plt.savefig("g3.19e10.01024.jpg")
plt.savefig("g3.19e10.01024.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
plt.savefig("your_file_name.png")
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 